# Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module when use firebase ui dependancy

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, build.gradle, firebaseui

I want to use RecycleView in my android project. For that I tried to add 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0' to my module gradle. After that I am getting an error as "Corrupt serialized resolution result. Cannot find selected module (287) for constraint platform-runtime -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"

I am new to android developments and I could not resolve this problem.

Here is my module gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    //id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bookmark"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //multidex Error fix

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' //Multidex error fix


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.2.0'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"



    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Error disappear when I comment `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0'`

Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my findings stuff like these are usually caused by corner cases in the dependency graph computation, so changing declaration order or adding / removing dependencies can make the problem go away.

And you should also try Clean project then Rebuild, and/or Invalidate cache and restart.

I had a similar problem and it resolved it.